# Split parameter in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to split one of the parameters in azure pipelines and use it for

```
parameters:
  - name: JDK_VERSION  # value is 1.17
    type: string
  - name: JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK
    type: string
```

---

```
jobs:
- job: J1_Buid_Application
    steps:
    # Install JDK 17
    - bash: |
        curl ${{parameters.JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK}} -L --output jdk.tar.gz
        displayName: "☕ Download JDK"
    - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
        inputs:
        versionSpec: ${{ split(parameters.JDK_VERSION, '.')[1] }}  # pure value to work properly is '17'
        jdkArchitectureOption: x64
        jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
        jdkFile: jdk.tar.gz
        jdkDestinationDirectory: jdk
        displayName: "☕ Install JDK"
```

Running the pipeline ends with:

```
Starting: ☕ Install JDK
==============================================================================
Task         : Java tool installer
Description  : Acquire a specific version of Java from a user-supplied Azure blob or the tool cache and sets JAVA_HOME
Version      : 0.231.4
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer
==============================================================================
##[error]Input required: versionSpec
##[error]Input required: versionSpec
Finishing: ☕ Install JDK
```

EDIT for Alvin Zhao

Main pipeline looks like:

```
variables:
- group: MAIN_VARIABLES

stages:
- stage: Install JDK
    displayName: Build application
    jobs:
    - template: templates/install_java.yaml
        parameters:
        JDK_VERSION: $(JDK_VERSION)
        JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK: $(JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK)
```

[image: Variable group in Libraly]

[image: Value of splitted is empty]

Comment: Hi @stefan.stt, Have you got a chance to test with the workaround in my updated answer below? The cause of the issue is `split` function could only be used in template expression `${{ expression }}` which is processed at compile time; but the value of the variable from a variable group is only accessible at runtime after compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I tested, the split function could only be used in template expression `${{ expression }}` which is processed at compile time; but the value of the variable from a variable group is only accessible at runtime after compile time. Therefore, we could not use split function to process the value of a variable in a variable group.

The workaround is to extract the expected value in script and use the output variable to define the `versionSpec` property in the subsequent task.

```
# Template: install_java.yaml
parameters:
- name: JDK_VERSION
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK
  type: string
  default: ''
jobs:
- job: J1_Buid_Application
  steps:
  # Install JDK
  - ${{if eq(parameters.JDK_VERSION, '$(JDK_VERSION)') }}: # This condtional insertion evaluates as true, because the value of parameters.JDK_VERSION at compile time is the string '$(JDK_VERSION)' rather than the variable's expanded value '1.17'
    - bash: |
        curl ${{parameters.JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK}} -L --output jdk.tar.gz
        SPLIT_JDK_VERSION=$(echo ${{parameters.JDK_VERSION}} | cut -d '.' -f 2)
        echo "SPLIT_JDK_VERSION is $SPLIT_JDK_VERSION"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SPLIT_JDK_VERSION]$SPLIT_JDK_VERSION"
      displayName: "☕ Download JDK"
    - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: $(SPLIT_JDK_VERSION)
        jdkArchitectureOption: x64
        jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
        jdkFile: jdk.tar.gz
        jdkDestinationDirectory: jdk
      displayName: "☕ Install JDK"
```

If you would use a [variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse) to store the variable values instead of a variable group, you may transfer variable values into template with template expression syntax. Thus, the split function works.

```
# main.yaml

variables:
# - group: MAIN_VARIABLES # Where the varaible $(JDK_VERSION) is defined with the value of 1.17
- template: ../TEMPLATE/MAIN_VARIABLES.yaml
stages:
- stage: Install_JDK
  displayName: Build application
  jobs:
  - template: ../TEMPLATE/install_java.yaml
    parameters:
      JDK_VERSION: ${{ variables.JDK_VERSION }}
      JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK: ${{ variables.JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK }}
```

---

Based on your description, I generated the demo YAML pipeline below, which was **able** to install the expected JDK.

I could reproduce the issue when this parameter value is empty `default: ''`. [image]

You may need to make sure the parameter `JDK_VERSION` has a valid value in [compile time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline) expressions (`${}`).

```
parameters:
- name: JDK_VERSION
  type: string
  default: 1.17
- name: JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK
  type: string
  default: https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
jobs:
- job: J1_Buid_Application
  steps:
  # Install JDK 17
  - bash: |
      curl ${{parameters.JDK_DOWNLOAD_LINK}} -L --output jdk.tar.gz
      echo "parameters.JDK_VERSION is ${{ parameters.JDK_VERSION }}"
      echo "Splitted JDK_VERSION is ${{ split(parameters.JDK_VERSION, '.')[1] }}"
    displayName: "☕ Download JDK"
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: ${{ split(parameters.JDK_VERSION, '.')[1] }}  # pure value to work properly is '17'
      jdkArchitectureOption: x64
      jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
      jdkFile: jdk.tar.gz
      jdkDestinationDirectory: jdk
    displayName: "☕ Install JDK"
```

[image]

Comment: This serves as template for several pipelines. The values of those parameters come from `variables: -group: MAIN_VARIABLES`. I guess this is the reason on compile time the parameter has no value.

Comment: So, your scenario is to pass the value of a variable in the `variable group: MAIN_VARIABLES` as the parameter of the YAML template, right? I think we can use runtime expression to split the transferred parameter value. Can you share your scenario in the post? I will update my answer with a further test accordingly.

Comment: There is an edit. As you can see, by my side the value of the plit is empty, which is very strange. I have added the default values as well exact coppy of your split usage

Comment: I share a workaround with my findings. Please feel welcome to check and test.